# Regarding asking a question

Tags: support, homework-and-exercises, answers, user-accounts, post-ban

Actually when I was a new user to the site, I posted the homework-type questions. But as the time passes I learn, and understand how to ask a good question, as I learn a lot from the site.

But now problem is that, if I have doubt, I can't ask a new question, because the site banned from asking the question for six months. I understand that it is not fair to ask it, but I am doing because I can do anything, because questions I asked when I was a new user, were simple and straightforward, if update them user of are watching the question, reverse the question to its original state, I do not know what to do now. Because if I update the question, a user pings that it was not the original.

Please, can anyone guide me on what to do now?

Comment: (May or may not apply here: *[Can doubt sometimes mean question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)*)